# Internal access modifier

Tags: c#

I have a 2 classes in a project like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class ClassA
    {
         internal int dataMember;
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class ClassB 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassA c = new ClassA();
            Console.Write(c.dataMember); //Cannot access??
        }
    }
}
```

I have used internal access modifier for the class A and its data member

Though class A's object can be created within the main of class b, but why I am not able to access its data member with the internal access specifier within the same assembly?

Here's the error that it gives in VS 2010:

> 'ConsoleApplication1.ClassA.dataMember' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: `dataMember` is accessible ([ideone](http://ideone.com/3xfBM)). Maybe you're lacking a `using System;` directive, so *`Console`* is not visible?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot showing your project layout, the code and the error message? That might give us some hints.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to. Your exact code - just adding a `using System;` directive - compiles for me.

Check that you've actually saved all the files etc - and if there's a compile-time error, include that in your question. Perhaps there's something else wrong in `ClassA` (that you haven't shown us) which is preventing that class from compiling?

Also check that these really *are* in the same project - not just in the same namespace.

Comment: @Akash: I suspect that the code you've posted isn't the code that you're building then - or that it's not *all* the code you're building. What you've posted really, really does work. Please copy and paste *all* the code you've got into the question. I very much doubt that this is a compiler problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting results this way:

```
    internal class A
    {
        internal int X = 5;
    }
    static class B
    {
        public static void Show()
        {
            A a = new A();
            MessageBox.Show(a.X.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        B.Show();
    }
```

and also this way:

```
    internal class A
    {
        internal int X = 5;
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        A a = new A();
        MessageBox.Show(a.X.ToString());
    }
```