# About internal access modifier in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm having a problem with *internal* access modifier. I also looked at [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280016/internal-access-modifier) and yet facing this question why following code is NOT recognizing members of BaseClass?

```
namespace Project1
{
    internal class BaseClass
    {
        public static int intM = 0;
    }
}


namespace Project1
{
    class TestAccess
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            BaseClass myBase = new BaseClass();
            Console.WriteLine(myBase.intM);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have the Using System; statement?

Comment: There is an error message that comes together with the problem. Did you read it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a problem with internal but apparently with static. Your class member is static and you are trying to access it through an instance.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is probably complaining, "Cannot access static member intM in non-static context". The problem is that intM is defined as static, basically meaning that it belongs to the class itself and not any one instance of it, and it can't be accessed as if it did belong to an instance. You would instead access this member as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(BaseClass.intM);
```

You don't even need to create a BaseClass instance to do this.

Comment: Thanks. the error message I was getting:   **Member 'Project1.BaseClass.intM' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead **   I have no idea how I did not notice static keyword in there. This is not my code but example I found on MSDN.